# Piping to system()?

Tags: c, linux, command-line

I have a binary that reads input with gets().

I would like to execute it using system() in my own program and pipe input to it. How would this be possible?

On command line I would just do `echo 'blabla' | ./a.out`. Now I want to basically do the same inside a C program, where the blabla is generated in that program, then a.out is executed and blabla piped to it.

I can not change the first program to accept command line arguments.

Answer (score 4):

> I have a binary that reads input with gets().

Don't use it.  `gets()` is unsafe to use under any circumstances.

In response to your question, you can use `popen()` to pipe input into a subprocess.

Comment: thank you, I will take alook at popen(). I did not use gets() myself there, it is just a binary I have for which I'm trying to write an buffer overflow exploit.

Comment: If you want to control the subprocess's stdin /and/ stdout, you'll need to do something more complicated.  Create three pipes, then fork.  In the child process, use `dup2` to set the pipes as stdin, stdout, and stderr, then execv your program.  The parent process can read and write the other ends of the pipes.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `system` actually runs a shell, so you can execute any shell command you want, including a pipeline. Unless you're generating output that you need to send in a loop or something like that, `popen` provides no advantage (in particular, it does not allow you to write to the program's `stdin` and also read from it's `stdout`). So you can just use `system` like this:

```
// generate the string you want to send
char str[256] = "blabla";

// sprintf it into a command string
char cmd[256];
sprintf(cmd, "echo '%s' | ./a.out", str);

// send the command string to system
system(cmd);
```